# Labels for favorites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks

I enjoy marking useful or interesting questions as favorites. Most of the time it's because I could have the same problem in the future, and I want to bookmark the working answer or some posted suggestions.

Sometimes the title of the question is confusing when I look my favorites list, and it is not clear to me why I saved that as favorite. It would be nice to be able to apply some optional text (a label) on my favorites.  Then I would have a better idea why the question is in my favorites list.